# Not able to get status of service powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, window, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a list of services in a text file. I am using that from Get-Content like below. But its not working while taking service from file. When just using get-service Service* and using below code it works. Please help me to fix the code with changes . **Set-Service** Line and the **if condition** line as **.Status and .Name** not working

```
$TEST= Get-Content "Somelocation\service.txt"

foreach ($service in $TEST )
{

    if($**service.Status** -eq "Stopped")
    {
              Set-Service $**service.Name** -StartupType Manual
              "Starting  $service"
              start-service $service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

    }
    else
    {
        "$service was already started."
    }
}
```

Note: I tried using ** to make word bold but not happen inside code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve the service instance using the `Get-Service` cmdlet in order to query the status:

```
$TEST= Get-Content "Somelocation\service.txt"

foreach ($service in $TEST )
{
    $serviceInstance = Get-Service $service
    if($serviceInstance.Status -eq "Stopped")
    {
              Set-Service $service -StartupType Manual
              "Starting  $service"
              $serviceInstance.Start()
    }
    else
    {
        "$service was already started."
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use start-service $Service in place of $serviceInstance.Start()

as the file have the service that needs to start one by one -dependent service

Comment: Yes, you can also use Start-Service

Comment: Thanks. My main issue was for the .Status and it got solved. I tried same thing but I got why it didnot worked , spell mistake inside.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider to accepting the answer ;-)